# Salesforce baseUrl in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I am using process builder to create a chatter post when certain data conditions are satisfied and I need to include the link  to an object in the post (e.g. https://na11.salesforce.com/{recordId}).

Given that it is not possible to access custom settings and custom labels from the process builder, **is there any other way to "configure" the base URL (e.g. https://na11.salesforce.com) so that I don't have to hard code it into the action step** and also be able to use automatic deployment tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option (not the best option thou) is to create a formula field in your object with the formula

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_340, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_340)) & Id
```

and select that field from the merge field list in the chatter post.

[image]

Note : System variables are starting to surface in Process builder

[Reference System-Provided Values in Process Builder](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_system_variables.htm)